# Java background service to automate POST requests

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have a Java service that reads data(including BLOB) from a table 'A', writes those data to table 'B' and upload the BLOB to a storage server as ByteArrayInputStream (Basically a small migration service). After the upload process is successfully completed, a boolean column is set to 1 on both tables. The service works in such a manner that a POST request is sent to a REST server and for each row copied, a location header is returned as the response. The resource method handling POST request looks like this.

```
@POST
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response migrateToMinio(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) throws Exception {
    tiedostoService = new TiedostoService();
    attachmentService = new AttachmentService();
    List<Tiedosto> tiedostoList = tiedostoService.getAllFiles();
    List<String> responseList = new ArrayList<>();
    Response r;
    Integer newRow;
    String responseData = null;
    int i=1;
    for (Tiedosto tiedosto : tiedostoList) {
        Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
        attachment.setCustomerId(tiedosto.getCustomerId());
        attachment.setSize(tiedosto.getFileSize());
        newRow = attachmentService.createNew(attachment);
        UriBuilder builder = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder();
        if (newRow == 1) {
            builder.path(Integer.toString(i));
            r = Response.created(builder.build()).build();
            responseData = r.getLocation().toString();
            i++;
        }
        responseList.add(responseData);
    }
    String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(responseList);
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(jsonString).build();
}
```

First, a JWT is generated via POST to an api and using that as bearer token, another POST is sent to "/rest/attachments", it returns status 200 after taking a while for processing, like this.

[image]

My question is, how can I implement a java background service(like a client that would run on the same physical machine as the server) that would send POST requests automatically to the REST server for migration process? On the first run, the background service should process the entire table and after that the background service needs to run periodically to check whether new rows have been added to the table and process them accordingly. I'm a Java noob and would really appreciate any sort of help/suggestions.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for asynchronous calls that make POST requests in the background on different threads. So your application is not blocked from running other operations. If that is the case, have a look at CompleteableFuture in Java 8. Or, you are looking to do it using Spring, you can use @Async that will do it for you. Just google it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, how can I implement a java background service(like a
>   client that would run on the same physical machine as the server) that
>   would send POST requests automatically to the REST server for
>   migration process?

You could use the [JAX-RS client API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/package-summary.html) to send HTTP `POST` requests to `localhost`:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
Response res = client.target("http://localhost/your/path/here").request("application/json").post(/* ... Entity that goes in the message body ... */);
```

> On the first run, the background service should process the entire
>   table and after that the background service needs to run periodically
>   to check whether new rows have been added to the table and process
>   them accordingly.

Fire the first (set of) HTTP request(s) immediately, then use an `ExecutorService` to fire an HTTP `POST` at a fixed rate (or fixed interval, depending on your specific needs):

```
public class ClientService {

    private static final ScheduledExecutorService EXECUTOR = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    private static final long INITIAL_DELAY = 10_000;
    private static final long UPDATE_RATE = 10_000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Fire first (full?) update trigger here
        fireInitialMigration();
        // For subsequent (incremental?) updates, schedule an HTTP POST to occur at a fixed rate:
        EXECUTOR.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> fireSubsequentUpdate(), INITIAL_DELAY, UPDATE_RATE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        // Keep main thread alive
        while (true);
    }

    private static void fireInitialMigration() {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        Response res = client.target("http://localhost/your/path/here").request("application/json").post(/* ... Entity that goes in the message body ... */);
    }

    private static void fireSubsequentUpdate() {
        // Similar to initialMigration(), but change Entity/set of HTTP POSTs according to your needs.
    }
}
```